# Ionic 2 - List update doesn't reflect in UI unless page is refreshed

Tags: ionic2

My template:

```
<ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let draft of drafts">
    <ion-item>
        <h2>Report draft header</h2>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item-options side="left">
        <button ion-button color="secondary" (click)="draftUpload(draft.report.pk)">
            <ion-icon name="md-cloud-upload"></ion-icon>
            Upload
        </button>
    </ion-item-options>
</ion-item-sliding>
```

In the controller, I do this:

```
draftUpload(pk) {
    this.dataService.uploadReport(pk);
    this.drafts = this.dataService.getDraftReports();
}
```

Here is the getDraftReports() functions:

```
getDraftReports() {
    var draftReports = [];
    let reportObj : any;
    this.storage.forEach((value, key, index) => {
        reportObj = JSON.parse(value);

        if(reportObj.report.uploaded=="no"){
            draftReports.push(reportObj);
        }
    });
return draftReports;
```

}

This doesn't work, although the DB changes are made. If I refresh the page, or navigate away and back, the list updates.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `this.dataService.getDraftReports();` can you add this code?

Comment: @suraj I added the code for the function.

Comment: `this.storage` is ionic-storage?

Comment: Yes, Ionic2 Storage: 

    import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.storage.foreach` returns a promise and hence is asynchronous.

Your `draftReports` array is returned before it is set.You need to return the promise :

```
getDraftReports(draftsHandler:any) {
    //var draftReports = []; 
    //Use a filter method and return the promise.       
    return this.storage.forEach((value, key, index) => {
        let reportObj : any;
        reportObj = JSON.parse(value);
        if(reportObj.report.uploaded=="no"){
            //draftReports.push(reportObj);
             draftsHandler(reportObj);
        }
    });
}
```

In your `draftUpload` set `drafts` within `then`.

```
draftUpload(pk) {
    this.dataService.uploadReport(pk);
    this.dataService.getDraftReports((data)=>this.draftsHandler(data)).then(()=>{
       //next steps
    }
}
   draftsHandler(data:any){
     this.drafts.push(data)
   }
```

Comment: do you mind explaining how the above works? You have to return statements. First you return the promise itself, then you also return reportObj inside the if condition.

I am getting some really weird results and this is the part I don't get. The goal is to return the promise with all the objects that meet the if condition.

Comment: yes.. getDraftReports will return the `forEach` function that you are returning. When `then` is called, it will resolve the forEach to return obj(s) that satisfy the condition.

Comment: what weird results are you getting?

Comment: I am getting just one object instead of many (which I expect) after the promise is run.

Comment: ok... the loop is breaking because it returns the first one it sees

Comment: you could send in a handler that will push into your array.. and just call then

Comment: That's what I thought, but I am not able to fix it given how un-intuitive I find  this whole async programming!

Yes please, edit it for my and others' sake.

Comment: it takes some getting used to.. I too come from a Java background.. :) but when you are in the middle of http callbacks coupled with app page lifecycle everything becomes async

Comment: try this one and let me know

Comment: Yes, that helped! Had to move draftsHandler around but this guided me to the solution and now I fully get the code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It seems a change detection issue. Change detection is fired on every browser event, timeout or http request.

The case is that your function: **getDraftReports()** is asyncronous and is its callback is not detected for Angular and consequently it doesn't fires the change detection event in order to update the view.

In order to solve this you will have to wrap this function into the angular zone. See this code:

import zone:

```
import {  NgZone } from '@angular/core';
```

Inject the service ngZone:

```
constructor(private zone: NgZone) {
    ....
}
```

And finally add this to your function:

```
draftUpload(pk) {
   this.dataService.uploadReport(pk);
   this.zone.run(
    () => {
       this.drafts = this.dataService.getDraftReports();
    }
   )
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, it will not work. Your function is returning an empty array. The thing is that forEach is a asynchronous . See @suraj response